# ASP.NET Core Asynchronous API Endpoint Return Extra Properties beside Actual Payload Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing the back end API in ASP.NET Core 5.0 with C#.

I see when using async method for my API endpoint response are return with extra properties like "exception", "status", "isCancelled", "result" etc. preparty. In "result" property the expected response data returned.

Returned JSON:

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "bette",
        "age": 40
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "cherry",
        "age": 65
    }
],
"id": 1,
"exception": null,
"status": 5,
"isCanceled": false,
"isCompleted": true,
"isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
"creationOptions": 0,
"asyncState": null,
"isFaulted": false
}
```

API Endpoint Repository Code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MemberDto>> GetMembersAsync()
{
    return await _context.Users
         .ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
         .ToListAsync();
}
```

Actual API Controller Endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MemberDto>>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = _userRepository.GetMembersAsync();
    return Ok(users);
}
```

Why getting such extra properties from the API?

Comment: That looks like the API endpoint is returning the `Task<T>` instead of the result of the task. Are you sure that's the endpoint that's being called, and there's not another method in between? If so, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Yes, you are right this returning Task<T>. 
I updated the question. Looks like the problem is in the upper layer at actual API Endpoint.


[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MemberDto>>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = _userRepository.GetMembersAsync();
    return Ok(users);
}

Comment: In the API endpoint you need to await the call to `_userRepository.GetMembersAsync`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller endpoint should be:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MemberDto>>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = await _userRepository.GetMembersAsync();
    return Ok(users);
}
```